# Is there any shortcut in Python to remove all blanks at the end of each line in a file?

Tags: python

I've learned that we can easily remove blank lined in a file or remove blanks for each string line, but how about remove all blanks at the end of each line in a file ?

One way should be processing each line for a file, like:

```
with open(file) as f:
  for line in f:
    store line.strip()
```

Is this the only way to complete the task ?

Comment: Definitively not the only way to complete the task, but looks like a pretty good one by any standards. You can also use `.rstrip()` to remove spacing only from the end of the line (and not from the beginning).

Comment: If you are not facing any issues, this question is better asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Havenard yes, `.rstrip()` should be the right one if only blanks at the end of line is needed to be removed. But how about shortcut to deal with the whole file, is it must to iterate every line in the file or we can have some other function to process at the file level ?

Comment: @DanielMesejo Thanks for you information, I didn't notice that till now :)

Comment: @DanielMesejo The problem is that lines aren't instances of their own, they exist as part of the file stream and determining where the line ends is only possible by reading the text file byte by byte, so you're lucky enough that Python already does most of the work for you, but it only goes so far as providing general use methods and functions. Performing the specific modification that you want will require your own coding.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the ugliest implementation possible but heres what I just scratched up :0

```
def strip_str(string):
    last_ind = 0
    split_string = string.split(' ')
    for ind, word in enumerate(split_string):
        if word == '\n':
            return ''.join([split_string[0]] + [ ' {} '.format(x) for x in split_string[1:last_ind]])
        last_ind += 1
```

Comment: Seems a little complex :) `rstrip()`, `lstrip()` or `strip()` might be enough if we only want to remove blanks at the beginning/end for one string line. Here I'm wandering if there is any file level function so we can call one function to remove all blank for all lines in a file, instead of iterating each line.

Comment: @PeterChan there is not one that I know of. You can just loop through each line and strip it with the above function, don't think there is an equivalent lower level implemented function that does the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if these count as different ways of accomplishing the task.  The first is really just a variation on what you have. The second does the whole file at once, rather than line-by-line.

1. Map that calls the 'rstrip' method on each line of the file.

   ```
   import operator

   with open(filename) as f:

       #basically the same as (line.rstrip() for line in f)
       for line in map(operator.methodcaller('rstrip'), f)):

           # do something with the line
   ```
2. read the whole file and use re.sub():

   ```
   import re

   with open(filename) as f:
       text = f.read()
       text = re.sub(r"\s+(?=\n)", "", text)
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You just want to remove spaces, another solution would be...

```
line.replace(" ", "")
```

Good to remove white spaces.

Comment: This will remove all the spaces at the end of the line, sure... But it will remove all the spaces at the beginning and in the middle, too.